# Java script operator / with decimal number

Tags: javascript

Why 170.5546/.0001 is 1705545.999999 but 170.5543/.0001 is 1705543 in java script, this thing I run ob browse.

In java script the / behavior is different, I tried in browser but not able to conclude it.    The behavior is different when I am calculating in calculator and Java

Comment: Read about floating point precision. p.s. If you try to evaluate 170.5546/0.0001 in Java, those are doubles with higher precision. Try 170.5546f/0.0001f in Java and you will see the same thing as in JS.

Comment: "_The behavior is different when I am calculating in calculator and Java_" - No, you will get the same result in Java.

Comment: @Ivar unless the numbers are doubles, which have different precision.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Numbers in JavaScript also have double floating point precision. `System.out.println(170.5546/.0001)` yields `1705545.9999999998`. (Using any/both as floats of course gives a different result.)